# GNU Fortran compiler is exporting all functions to my DLL

Tags: dll, fortran

I am compiling a Fortran DLL with GNU fortran compiler (IDE : Code::Blocks 20.03).

In my code, I have the following subroutine:

```
SUBROUTINE C3400114(Tabin,Tabout)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::C3400114
...
```

This is the only subroutine that has DLLEXPORT. However, when I open the DLL with Dependency Walker, all my subroutines are exported, not only that one.
In addition, the uppercase of my function is not respected, as the function is exported as 'c3400114'.
[image]

As compiler options, I have the following:

`-fPIC -DBUILD_DLL -Wtabs -fno-automatic -fdollar-ok -fno-underscoring -fno-second-underscore`

As linker options, I have the following: `-static -mrtd -shared -Wl,--kill-at`.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at `-fvisibility=hidden` in the GCC Code Generation Options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html. As Steve says, you may need to use `!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT`. More information can be found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the "exports all" issue, but Fortran is case-insensitive and different compiler/platform combinations have different conventions for external names. gfortran, in particular, downcases names and adds a trailing underscore.

If you want the subroutine to have a specific, case-sensitive name, use the `BIND(C),NAME=` language binding attribute. For example:

`SUBROUTINE C3400114(Tabin,Tabout) BIND(C,NAME="C3400114")`

This will require that the procedure arguments be "interoperable".

I do note your use of `!DEC$` as a directive introducer. Perhaps gfortran supports that (I don't know). gfortran does support `!GCC$` and perhaps `!DIR$` (Intel Fortran supports the latter.)